# Scrapy Xpath: How can I avoid getting the same value within the same page?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get values below from html looks like below with Scrapy.

```
<div class="product_sec">
<h4><span class="">
<a href="/sampleindex.html" class="detail">Product1</a>
</span></h4>

<h4><span class="">
<a href="/sampleindex.html" class="detail">Product2</a>
</span></h4>
---Continues to Product 50---
</div>
```

There are in total 50 Products on the page.

What I need is the list of the text Product1, Product2 but when I run the code below,

```
def parse(self, response):
    for post in response.xpath('//*[@class="product_sec"]'):
        yield ProductItem(
            title = response.xpath('//a[@class="detail"]/text()').get()
        )
```

It gives me the list of Product1 x 50 times instead of Product1, Product2...
I have tried to set the right value by changing Xpath but it always gives me the same result.
It looks like this 'for' sentence always take the first value.
How shall I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **relative** Xpath expression:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for post in response.xpath('//*[@class="product_sec"]'):
        yield ProductItem(
            title = post.xpath('.//a[@class="detail"]/text()').get()
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

replace your `response.xpath` to the object you are trying to loop

```
def parse(self, response):
    for post in response.xpath('//*[@class="product_sec"]'):
        yield ProductItem(
            title = post.xpath('a[@class="detail"]/text()').extract()
        )
```

Comment: I tried what you have kindly adviced, but it gets me the same results, 50 times of Product1....

Comment: tried this , but still same results      title = response.xpath('//*[@class="product_sec"][1]/a[@class="detail"][1]/text()').get()